# Finding the area swept out by a polar equation

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, polar-coordinates

Find the area of surface where $x=r\cos(\alpha)$ and $y=r\sin\alpha$ , where $(x^2 + y^2)^3 = x^4 + y^4$

I simplified the equation

$$r^2 = 3/4 + (\cos4\alpha)/4$$

from equation it is clear that

$$2^{-1/2} < r < (3/4 + (\cos4\alpha)/4)^{1/2}$$

and

$$0 < \alpha < \pi/4$$

after combining the integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}d\alpha \int_{2^{-1/2}}^{(3/4 + (\cos4\alpha)/4)^{1/2}}r dr
$$ and solving this i get $\pi/32$ which is wrong answer,

Please show me, where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

$A=\frac12\int_{0}^{2\pi} r^2 \,d\alpha=1/8 \int_{0}^{2\pi} (3 + \cos 4\alpha)\,d\alpha=\cdots=\frac{3\pi}4$

Comment: thanks for answer

how did you get that

$0<=\alpha <= 2\pi$?

Comment: The equation $r=1/2\sqrt{3+\cos 4\alpha}$ is defined in all quadrants (a closed symmetrical curve).

Comment: yes, but from that , $4\alpha$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$ , and so $\alpha$ is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, isn't it?

Comment: No, $x=r\cos \alpha, \, y = r\sin \alpha, \quad \color{red}{\alpha \in \langle 0,2\pi)}$.